# How to make a light off effect in an entire Table Row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me how to make a `lights off effect` in an entire `table row` if i click a specific textbox and remove the lights off effect if i click again the specific textbox and goes the same with other `textboxes` with there specific table rows.

My problem is when i click a specific textbox the textbox is the only one who is highlighted. I want it to be the entire table row on that specific textbox.

current code: http://jsfiddle.net/AP6kr/4/

Comment: Pleaes post your code into gthe question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target `$(this).parent()` instead of `$(this)`, you'll get the whole row.  See JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AP6kr/6/

My example is actually targeting the `<td>` tag, which is the parent of the input.  Since it's the only td in the row, it looks the same as if you go up one more parent to the `<tr>` tag.  you can see that effect here:  http://jsfiddle.net/AP6kr/8/

It's pretty much indistinguishable now, but if you had more cells per row it would matter.

Comment: You could also use `closest( "tr" )` instead of stacking `.parent()`. For some reasons the row isn't highlighted even with the class on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pointer-events:none;` on `#overlay` : http://jsfiddle.net/AP6kr/5/